# Cannot Apply Action in Inline Editing on Object Table. Got [Default] Internal Error

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have an object type calls TLT, it is a table of multiple columns. One of the columns is named "remark" and is left all Null. I created an action type calls "Modify TLT1" with the intention that users can add/edit remarks whenever they need to directly on the workshop dashboard. But when I enable Inline Editing switch and add that "Modify TLT" action type in the field and then proceed to add some value into the remark field I got the error: "Failed to apply change. Error: [Default] Internal. The Error ID is useless. The data table is CUI so I cannot post on here. If anyone have any idea what that error is about, I would really appreciate the guidance.

I tried to switch up everything I can in Ontology Manager, including Rules, Form, Properties, etc but nothing worked. I got the same error message every single time.